# Put a character between strings

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have this XML file containing:

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT005_">
<wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:PERNR>00000001</wd:PERNR>
    <wd:HR_PARTNER>
        <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>A</wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
    </wd:HR_PARTNER>
    <wd:HR_PARTNER>
        <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>B</wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
    </wd:HR_PARTNER>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:PERNR>00000002</wd:PERNR>
    <wd:HR_PARTNER>
        <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>C</wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
    </wd:HR_PARTNER>
    <wd:HR_PARTNER>
        <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>D</wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
    </wd:HR_PARTNER>
    <wd:HR_PARTNER>
        <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>E</wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
    </wd:HR_PARTNER>
</wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

And I'm using XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="wd"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT005_">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
    <wd:Report_Data>
      <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
      <wd:Report_Entry>
       <wd:PERNR><xsl:value-of select="wd:PERNR"/></wd:PERNR>
       <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:HR_PARTNER/*"/>
       </wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
      </wd:Report_Entry>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </wd:Report_Data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wd:HR_PARTNER">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::wd:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:with-param name="HRBP" select="current()" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/wd:HR_PARTNER">
    <xsl:param name="HRBP"/>
    <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
        <xsl:value-of select="$HRBP"/>
    </wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This seems works fine however I need to put a space between the values of wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART. I'm not really good in coding so I'm not sure of the other ways to use here. Does someone know how can I do it so my final output will look like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT005_">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:PERNR>00000001</wd:PERNR>
    <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>A B</wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:PERNR>00000002</wd:PERNR>
    <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>C D E</wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
   <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:HR_PARTNER/*"/>
   </wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
```

simply use

```
   <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
     <xsl:value-of select="wd:HR_PARTNER/wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART" separator=" "/>
   </wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
```

The space is the separator character is even the default for `value-of` with a `select` attribute (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of) so you could simply use

```
   <wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
     <xsl:value-of select="wd:HR_PARTNER/wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART"/>
   </wd:HR_BUSINESS_PART>
```